# Remove garbage characters in utf

Tags: php, regex, arabic

I am using utf8 format to store all my data into mysql. Before data is inserted into the database I need to clean the strings with unwanted characters. The strings are in utf8 format. I know how to use regex and string replace but do not know how to work with arabic characters.

Sample string that needs to be cleaned : "████ .. الــقــوانين الجديـــدة في قســـم الـعنايـ";

Thanking you

Comment: Are there any wanted Arabic characters?  Unicode allocates a few ranges to Arabic; can you leverage off those ranges?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - i meant 'unwanted characters' . Fixed. Yes but how do I get the unicode of a letter in a string before I check if it lies in a range?

Comment: @Imran: You don't need it. Just specify the range you don't want. The regex could then be (in words): *replace all characters in this range by an empty string*. The regex engine figures out whether the character is in the range or not.

Comment: @Felix Kling - so how to I specify range of unicode? example would be nice, I can easily find the range.

Comment: @Imran: `[\x{FFFF}-\x{FFFF}]` should do it and you have to set the `u` modifier to turn on unicode. See here for more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Comment: @Felix Kling - echo preg_replace('[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]','',$string); ?

Comment: @Felix Kling - Compilation failed: character value in \x{...} sequence is too large at offset 7

Comment: @Imran: Well, you have to pass a proper formated expression. Try: `preg_replace('/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]/u','',$string)`.

Comment: @Felix Kling - wow good it removed the arabic, how do I not the 'not' expression so I can have it the other way round?

Comment: @Felix Kling - ok preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]/u','',$string); works. You can put your answer below so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: @Felix: take your comments and make them into an answer.  Note that there is an 'Arabic Supplemental' range U+0750..U+077F, an Arabic Presentation Forms A in the range U+FB50..U+FC3F, and Arabic Presentation Forms B in the range U+FE70..U+FEFC.  You can find the information at [Unicode Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).  I had the files downloaded from playing with this a year or two ago.

Comment: @Jonathan: Actually I thought *you* should create an answer because you started with unicode ranges ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler , @Felix Kling  -  i thought i should be the one to decide

Comment: @Imran: Note that I added a `+` after the the character class so that it matches *one or more characters*. This is a better than replacing every single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. As [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) already said, if you can specify the unicode character ranges for the characters that need to be replaced, you can use a regular expression to replace the characters with an empty string.

A unicode character is specified as `\x{FFFF}` in an expression (in PHP). In addition, you have to set the [`u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make PHP treat the pattern as UTF8.

So in the end, you have something like this:

```
preg_replace('/[\x{FFFF}-\x{FFFF}]+/u','',$string);
```

where

- `/.../u` are the delimiters plus the modifier
- `[...]+` is a character class plus quantifier, which means *match any of these characters inside one or mor times*
- `\x{FFFF}-\x{FFFF}` is a unicode character range (obviously you have to provide the right codepoints/numbers of the characters).

You can also **negate** the group with a `^` you can specify the range which you want to keep:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{FFFF}-\x{FFFF}]+/u','',$string);
```

---

**More information:**

- [Regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Regular expressions in PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)
- [Unicode Charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/)

Comment: @Imran: That is fine, I just had the feeling that I just jumped on the wagon and @Jonathan actually had the right idea.... but anyways :)

Comment: @Felix - you had the PHP knowledge that was needed; I only started the ball rolling.  You did the rest - thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks for rolling the ball :)