# Remove garbage characters in arabic

Tags: php, regex

I needed to remove all non Arabic characters from a string and eventually [with the help of people from stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642341/remove-garbage-characters-in-utf/6643116#6643116) was able to come up with the following regex to get rid of all characters which are not Arabic.

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]/u','',$string);
```

The problem is the above removes white spaces too. And now I discovered I would need character from `A-Z,a-z,0-9, !@#$%^&*()` also. So how do I need to modify the regex?

Thanking you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the ones you want to keep to your character class:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}A-Za-z !@#$%^&*()]/u','', $string);
```

Answer (score 5):

assume you have this string:

```
$str = "Arabic Text نص عربي test 123 و,.m,............ ~~~ ٍ،]ٍْ}~ِ]ٍ}";
```

this will keep arabic chars with spaces only.

```
echo preg_replace('/[^أ-ي ]/ui', '', $str);
```

this will keep Arabic and English chars with Numbers Only

```
echo preg_replace('/[^أ-يA-Za-z0-9 ]/ui', '', $str);
```

this will answer your question latterly.

```
echo preg_replace('/[^أ-يA-Za-z !@#$%^&*()]/ui', '', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks, the code to keep arabic chars with spaces only. I had to change it to include two missing arabic chars ء and آ echo preg_replace('/[^أ-ي آء]/ui', '', $str);

Answer (score 0):

In a more detailed manner from Above example, Considering below is your string:

```
$string = '<div>This..</div> <a>is<a/> <strong>hello</strong> <i>world</i> ! هذا هو مرحبا العالم! !@#$%^&&**(*)<>?:";p[]"/.,\|`~1@#$%^&^&*(()908978867564564534423412313`1`` "Arabic Text نص عربي test 123 و,.m,............ ~~~ ٍ،]ٍْ}~ِ]ٍ}"; ';
```

Code:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}A-Za-z0-9 !@#$%^&*().]/u','', strip_tags($string));
```

`Allows:` English letters, Arabic letters, 0 to 9 and characters `!@#$%^&*().`

`Removes:` All html tags, and special characters other than above