# Strip non alphanumeric characters from Arabic UTF8 + English string

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, arabic, ereg-replace

I want to remove all non Arabic, non English and non Numbers charecters from a string, except for dashes (-).

I managed to do it for non English alphanumeric characters like this:

```
$slug = ereg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9-]', '', $string);
```

But for non arabic alphanumeric characters i tried to do it like this:

```
$slug = ereg_replace('\p{InArabic}', '', $string);
```

but it didnt strip the non alphanumeric characters! I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643148/remove-garbage-characters-in-arabic) but it didnt work either, it always returns '0' !!

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^\x{0600}-\x{06FF}A-Za-z0-9-]/u','', $string);
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: `ereg_replace` is deprecated. The regex with `preg_replace` should work. Could you provide sample strings where it doesn't work?

Comment: What is the output of `preg_last_error()`? The code snippet works.

Comment: Thank you M42, that worked with the help of "xdazz" answer, thank you all guys.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the below:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^\p{Arabic}\da-z-]/ui', '', $string);
```

Comment: hey,this function also remove space from string,how to keep space between string..?

Comment: @s4suryapal Add space to it.

Comment: This regex causes error with large datasets: Segmentation fault (core dumped)